# How to make changes to UITableViewCell from navigationBar?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

How can I make layout changes to a UITableViewCell from the navigation bar of a UITableViewController? It feels like I've tried everything, but to no avail.

This is the controller:

```swift
    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
        
        let tableViewCellID = "tableViewCellID"
        
        //MARK: Loading view
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableViewCellID)
            
            navigationBar()
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            guard let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellID) as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            
            tableViewCell.firstLayout()
            
            return tableViewCell
        }
        
        func navigationBar() {
            
            let emptyButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
            
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [emptyButton]
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        }
        
        @objc func buttonTapped() {
            
            let tableViewCell = TableViewCell()
            
            tableViewCell.secondLayout()
        }
    }
```

This is the cell:

```swift
    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        
        let firstColorView: UIView = {
            let coverView = UIView()
            coverView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            coverView.backgroundColor = .red
            return coverView
        }()
        
        let secondColorView: UIView = {
            let cameraViewClosure = UIView()
            cameraViewClosure.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cameraViewClosure.backgroundColor = .yellow
            return cameraViewClosure
        }()
        
        func firstLayout() {
            
            contentView.addSubview(firstColorView)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                firstColorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
                firstColorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            ])
        }
        
        func secondLayout() {

            print("This prints, but no changes are made to the cell")
            
            contentView.addSubview(secondColorView)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                secondColorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
                secondColorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1),
                secondColorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            ])
        }
    }
```

I have of course tried all these:

```swift
    layoutIfNeeded()
    setNeedsLayout()
    setNeedsDisplay()
    layoutSubviews()
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    updateConstraints()
    updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

... and I have tried them in all kinds combinations, but I still don't get the results I want.

Let me know if you need anymore code or information, please and thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following modifications.

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
    let cell = tableView.visibleCells.first as? TableViewCell
    cell?.secondLayout()
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Much obliged. Do you have any documentation that you can link to?

Comment: Here is the documentation for those that are interested: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells